# Swift, Parse currentInstallation() - output channels on different views

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm working with parse.com push notifications.

On one view, users can subscribe to notifications. I use:

```
    let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.addUniqueObject(self.gameID, forKey: "channels")
    currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
```

I output the channels:

```
    print(currentInstallation.channels as! [String])
```

Works great!  Outputs the current subscribed channels.

Now, on another view, I have the same thing.

```
    let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
```

and the print statement.  However, the print statement returns nil.  Any idea how on the other view, I can also get the list of currently subscribed to channels?

Comment: Sounds like an odd error. Maybe theres an error elsewhere in your second view. What if you fetched the data on the second view , something like             PFInstallation.currentInstallation().fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (currentInstallation, error) -> Void in
                
            })

Comment: If I print that statement out, I get `()` - is that what you meant?

Comment: Emm, No I mean, Copy this code into your second view.         PFInstallation.currentInstallation().fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (currentInstallation, error) -> Void in
            let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
            print(currentInstallation.channels as! [String])
        })

Comment: That worked!  So... the difference is... you fetched the data back from parse.com instead of using my app's data?  Thanks!

Comment: Yea, but its strange that the local installation doesn't save itself. My solution may be masking an underlying bug.